# How can I format RSS feed content description?

Tags: php

I would like format the my RSS feed content. Like embed some information with Description tag. I am creating Wordpress Rss feed and trying to create rss 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<item>
<title>firstquestion</title>
<url>test-domain.com</url>
<description>This is some ifnormation on the description. The below are the answers for the new question</description></item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Now, I want to format or further some table or information to be attached with special characters, even html tags formatting in the `<description>` ... How can I do that?

When I simply insert , it gives me an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have HTML inside the description element, but you have to encode it using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

```
$description = '<strong>Strong formatting</strong> or <em>emphasis</em>.';
$item = '<item>
           <title>firstquestion</title>
           <url>test-domain.com</url>
           <description>'.htmlspecialchars($description).'</description>
         </item>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) sections:

```
$description = '<strong>Strong formatting</strong> or <em>emphasis</em>.';
$item = '<item>
           <title>firstquestion</title>
           <url>test-domain.com</url>
           <description><![CDATA['.$description.']]></description>
         </item>';
```